# kendo ui grid get nulled on first data when hit save on toolbar

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

hi i recently trying kendo ui and it's looks promising

but when i'm try batch editing i found many problem, for now i use mock array object data to simulate view, success, i tried batch editing

short story, i try to save the edited column, and when the save button clicked, first row get nulled, but data below it still preserve including the edited ones

here's the JS

```
var dataDS = [{ type: "B0998", quantity: "2", harga: "12000", jumlah: "4", saldo: "200000", nama_barang: "sundanese fries (fried singkong)" },

    { type: "B0998", quantity: "2", harga: "12000", jumlah: "4", saldo: "200000", nama_barang: "fried tempe" },
    {
        type: "B0999", quantity: "2", harga: "15000", jumlah: "4", saldo: "502000", nama_barang: "rounded toufu"
    },
    {
        type: "B0999", quantity: "2", harga: "15000", jumlah: "4", saldo: "502000", nama_barang: "sundanese salad"
    }, {
        type: "B0999", quantity: "2", harga: "15000", jumlah: "4", saldo: "502000", nama_barang: "goyobod ice"
    }
    , {
        type: "B0999", quantity: "2", harga: "15000", jumlah: "4", saldo: "502000", nama_barang: "roasted jenkol"
    }



];




var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource
({
    data: dataDS,
    pageSize: 5,
    batch: true,
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields:
            {
                type: { type: "string", editable: true, nullable: false },
                quantity: { type: "number", editable: true },
                harga: { type: "number", editable: true },
                jumlah: { type: "number", editable: true },
                saldo: { type: "number", editable: true },
                nama_barang: { type: "string", editable: true }
            }
        }
    }
})


$("#grid-placement").kendoGrid({

    dataSource: dataSource

        ,
    sortable: true,
    editable: true,

    toolbar: ["create","edit", "save", "cancel"],
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true
    },
    editable: true,
    columns: [
        {
            field: "type",
            title: "Type"
        },
        {
            field: "quantity",
            title: "Quantity"
        },
        {
            field: "harga",
            title: "Harga"
        },
        {
            field: "jumlah",
            title: "Jumlah"
        },
        {
            field: "saldo",
            title: "Saldo"
        },
        {
            field: "nama_barang",
            title: "Nama Barang"
        },
        {
            command: "destroy", title: "delete"
        }


    ]
});
```

and here's the html

```
<div id="grid-placement" >
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using batch editing (or editing in general) on a KendoUI grid you have to specify the CRUD operations of the data source.

There are multiple ways to define the CRUD operations.
Following you can find a sample for work with local data.

Additional (and more detailed) information can be found on the KendoUI data source  [docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud).

```
transport: {
  read: function(options) {
    // Implement read
    options.success([/* Some data */]);
  },
  create: function(options) {
    // Implement create
    options.success();
  },
  update: function(options) {
    // Implement update
    options.success();
  },
  destroy: function(options) {
    // Implement destroy
    options.success();
  }
}
```

I've put together a working Dojo based on your sample. ([Link](http://dojo.telerik.com/aGODa))

The changes are not saved to the array however, so when you click the refresh buttons the changes will disappear, as it reads the original array again.

Comment: darn, so that's how it works

thanks i'm very new in kendo and i still wondering how it work, especially for data collecting

i was thinking to make event manually